# Using V.clean.snap?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, snapping

I'm working on creating a road network of pedestrian walkways. Since all data were manually drawn, I'll need to snap the vertices together to form a consistent road network on which I can run routing. I tried to use V.clean to snap all vertices within a certain distance but V.clean.snap always reported errors.

Is anyone able to help me out?

[image]

Comment: I guess that one of the column names might be a reserved SQL word. Could you try with renamed column names?